# HasAnyAuthority always let me in into the api whenever it is declared to stop the request

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization

Going through Spring Security I created a method:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/build/app.js", "/static/app/styles/*/**", "/static/app/js/*/**",
                        "/static/build/libs.js", "/index.html", "/static/build/*/**", "/", "/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/registerClient").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checklogin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/getAllAdmins").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.WORKER)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
```

And example of the controller method:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/vehicle")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN', 'CLIENT')")
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<VehicleReservationModel> getVehiclesForClientByLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Principal name = request.getUserPrincipal();
    if (name.getName() == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Brak sesji");
    }
    if (roleService.getRoleForUserByLogin(name.getName()).toLowerCase().equals("admin")) {
        return vehicleService.getAllVehicles();
    } else {
        List<VehicleReservationModel> vehicleList = vehicleService.getVehiclesForClientByLogin(name.getName());
        if (vehicleList == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Brak pojazdów dla klienta " + name.getName() + " - lista jest pusta");
        }
        return vehicleList;
    }
}
```

The case is whenever I remove the `ADMIN` from

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN', 'CLIENT')")
```

and comment:

```java
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.WORKER)
```

it **always** let me in into the API. I thought whenever I create some privilidges, it will always work. Why in above example my Spring Security doesnt work?

**UPDATE:**
The answear is to enable using annotation `PreAuthorize` you need to add :
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You enabled [`@Secured`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/annotation/Secured.html) with [`EnableGlobalMethodSecurity#securedEnabled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html#securedEnabled--):

> Determines if Spring Security's Secured annotations should be enabled.

but you have to enable [`@PreAuthorize`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.html) with [`EnableGlobalMethodSecurity#prePostEnabled`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html#prePostEnabled--):

> Determines if Spring Security's pre post annotations should be enabled. Default is false.

Your modified Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/static/build/app.js", "/static/app/styles/*/**", "/static/app/js/*/**",
                    "/static/build/libs.js", "/index.html", "/static/build/*/**", "/", "/static/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/registerClient").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checklogin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/getAllAdmins").permitAll()
                // .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.CLIENT, AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.WORKER)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/")
                .permitAll();
```